# Implementing While loop so my code repeats itself properly

Tags: java

In my code:

```
  public static String input() {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         
     while(true) {         
        int qcount = 0;
        String key = input.nextLine();
        char[] keyCharArray = key.toCharArray();
    
        for (int i = 0; i<keyCharArray.length;i++) {

           //Here the while loop is supposed to break

           if(keyCharArray[i]=='q') {
              qcount++;            
              break;            
           }
        }
                       
        int[] radie = new int[(keyCharArray.length)/2];
        int[] höjd = new int[(keyCharArray.length)/2];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < keyCharArray.length; i++){    
           if(i % 2 == 0){    
              radie[i/2] = keyCharArray[i] - '0';
           }
           else if(i % 2 != 0){    
              höjd[i/2] = keyCharArray[i] - '0';            
           }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < (keyCharArray.length)/2; i++) {               
           System.out.print("r = " + radie[i] + " " + "h = " + höjd[i] + "\n\r" + "Basytans area: " + area(radie[i], höjd[i]) + "\n\r" + "Mantelytans area:" + area(radie[i]) + "\n\r" + "Volym: " + volume(radie[i], höjd[i]) + "\n\r");
        }
     
        return key;        
     }
  }
```

The While loop is supposed to repeat the content until keyCharArray[i] =='q' -> There after the while loop is supposed to break

How can I make this work? Thanks

I have tried everything, yet I can't seem to solve it.

Appreciate any efforts, Thanks alot

Tried everything, doesn't work

sadasd

dsadsa

sdadsa

asdsda

Comment: Put the exit-loop check in a separate function, that returns a `boolean` value if the `while` loop should exit or not? Like `if (shouldExit(key)) { break; }`?

Comment: Forgive me for being stupid, could you elaborate? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it supposed to quit if `q` is anywhere in the input, or if their entire input is just "q"?

Answer (score 0):

You current code is (partially) like this:

```
public static String input(){

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(true){
    int qcount = 0;
    String key = input.nextLine();
    char[] keyCharArray = key.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i<keyCharArray.length;i++) {
      if(keyCharArray[i]=='q') {
        qcount++;
        break;
      }
    }

    // The rest...
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that the `break` only breaks the inner `for` loop.

The simplest solution is to use the `qcount` variable you already have, and *after* the `for` loop check if it's non-zero to `break` out of the `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<keyCharArray.length;i++) {
  if(keyCharArray[i]=='q') {
    qcount++;
    break;
  }
}
if (qcount > 0) {
  break;  // Breaks out of the while loop
}
```

---

As for my suggestion in the comment it would be something like this instead:

```
private boolean shouldBreak(String key) {
  char[] keyCharArray = key.toCharArray();

  for (int i = 0; i<keyCharArray.length;i++) {
    if(keyCharArray[i]=='q') {
      return true;  // Return that we should break the while loop
    }
  }

  return false;  // Do not break the while loop
}

public static String input(){

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(true){
    String key = input.nextLine();

    if (shouldBreak(key)) {
      break;  // Breaks out of the while loop
    }

    // The rest...
  }
}
```

I personally recommend something like this, as it makes the code cleaner and easier to read and understand and maintain.

Comment: In this case you don't need the separate method because you can use an existing method to find the answer - `if (key.indexOf('q') != -1) { break; }`